# Simulator crashes "[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil object at 0' "

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I am working on an application that will utilize a custom image picker and try as I might, I can not seem to get the application to run quite right.
Xcode debugger flags the following "Thread 1: Program recieved signal: "SIGABRT"."

```
  - (id) init { 
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _images =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _thumbs =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image {
    [_images addObject:image];
    [_thumbs addObject:[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(64, 64)]];
}
```

This is in xcode 4 on the new debugger.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: read the exception again. Either `image` or `[image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:]` is nil. Most likely your image scaling method doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Where is imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize defined? If it's returning nil, you'll get that error. As you will if image is nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of those objects is nil. The following code will help you discover which one:

```
- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image 
{
    if (image)
    {
        [_images addObject:image];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"image is nil");
    }

    UIImage *newImage = [image imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(64, 64)];
    if (newImage)
    {
        [_thumbs addObject:newImage];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"newImage is nil");
    }
}
```